# I want to be able to programmatically insert (linked) slides from a Google presentation into a Google Document using the API

Tags: google-docs-api, google-slides-api

I have a set of slides and want to be able to create documents that include a number of these slides. I cannot see any functions in the references for the API that allow me to create a document then include (linked) slides. This can be done manually through the user interface by simply opening the document and the presentation and copying and pasting the slides as links into the document. I want to be able to do this programmaticaly. Any assistance greatly appreciated.

I have looked through the references and can't see anything that will help

I would like to something like:

```
 var doc = DocumentApp.create('A document of Slides');

// doc.insertLink(slideID)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please tell us what you've tried? Thanks!

Comment: I have read through the google-docs-api and the google-slides-api it does not seem to contain any function to do what I have asked.